# How to make org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor to log in custom log file

Tags: java, cxf

In the application that am working on org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor is currently logging HTTP request/responses into catalina.out.

I want it to somehow duplicate this info into a separate log file.
Any pointers of how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the logging framework you are using, you should properly configure the `log4j`, `slf4j` or `<tomcat>/conf/logging.properties` file to set a specific appender for the `org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor` class.

Answer (score 5):

Wanted to share final solution that worked nicely for me.

Added following to the application's log4j.properties

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor=INFO, queryLog
log4j.additivity.org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor=true

log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor=INFO, queryLog
log4j.additivity.org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor=true

# Query log
log4j.appender.queryLog=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.queryLog.File=/C:/Eclipse-Tomcat/logs/query.log
log4j.appender.queryLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.queryLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.queryLog.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.category.queryLogger=INFO, queryLog
```

This basically works great for me, input/output HTTP request responses are logged in catalina.out as well as query.log Logs get rotated daily as well.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Javadoc](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/interceptor/LoggingInInterceptor.html), you could declare a new PrintWriter in the LoggingInInterceptor constructor :

```
File file = new File("/directory/mylogs.txt");
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
LoggingInInterceptor loggingInInterceptor = new LoggingInInterceptor(printWriter);
```

Answer (score 0):

The settings provided by OP's answer also worked for me(thanks!) however I had to change the LoggingOutInterceptor class name to the class that was was was running the service.

So instead of the following:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor=INFO, queryLog
log4j.additivity.org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor=true
```

I needed to have this:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.cxf.services=INFO, outgoingSOAPMessages
log4j.additivity.org.apache.cxf.services=true
```

Just thought I'd post in case it helps anyone in the future.